# SilverStripe default email style

Tags: silverstripe

Is it possible with SilverStripe 3 to create a default email template/style which is applied to all sent emails, without have to to override each email template separately?

Ideally this could be done as part of a theme.

I've tried defining a custom `GenericEmail.ss` template but it's been ignored thus far.

Looking at the framework source, creating a custom `Email` class and overriding the `parseVariables()` could possibly achieve it, but it seems like overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying just now, the default email template can effectively be overriden with a custom one. I put mine under the "templates" folder of my theme (and not in any subfolder), ie
/themes/mytheme/templates/GenericEmail.ss

Then tested after a flush=1 (so that the new template is picked up)

Hope this helps

Comment: It looks like it works as long as the email being sent doesn't already have a template. It looks like `Mailer->sendHTML()` checks if the template has an opening `<body>` tag, and if not, inserts a generic wrapper, ignoring `GenericEmail.ss`.

Comment: I guess you could build a custom `Mailer` and override `sendHTML()` and modify the `$htmlContent` first?

Comment: The wrapper used for cases where the body tag is missing takes care of reusing $htmlContent as the innerhtml of the body tag, so it would respect the prerendered email (in Email@parseVariables()). Having a body tag in GenericEmail.ss would circumvent the wrapper, if that's an issue

Comment: But for something like `ChangePasswordEmail`, which has a default template, and doesn't have a `<body>` by default, skips using `GenericEmail.ss` since it has it's own. That's when `Mailer::sendHTML()` picks it up and inserts a hard-coded html/body setup.

Comment: I understand your issue a bit better now. You want to use a custom wrapper for all emails, but keep using the out of the box templates; I didn't get that from the initial request. In that case, yes, subclassing Mailer as in your second comment is probably the best approach. You can then use Mailer::set_mailer() in mysite/_config.php so that all emails sent would use that custom mailer